# How to catch exceptions in your ZF2 controllers?

Tags: php, exception, try-catch, zend-framework2

I've setup the [ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) with `ZF 2.0.3` and I am unable to catch exceptions in my controllers. For instance if I put the below piece of code in `module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php`:

```
public function indexAction() {
    echo "BEFORE\n";
    try {
        throw new \Exception("My exception");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Caught exception $e\n";
        exit;
    }
```

and access the page I get:

```
BEFORE
An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:
Exception

File:

    module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php:25

Message:

    My exception
```

the `ViewModel` kicks in and displays the exception, effectively preventing me from catching it.

**How can I catch exceptions in `ZF2` controllers?**

Comment: is the controller in the global namespace? otherwise, you must either use \Exception or catch \Exception

Comment: Just a comment on the exception handling style you're using.  I'd be disinclined to catch Exception as that's too generic. What you're basically saying with that is "I intend to handle every possible exception that may occur here".  If your code calls other methods that may throw exceptions and that code may in turn also call exception-throwing code it can become very difficult to trace the source of the original error.  I'd suggest using a catch block for every kind of exception you're expecting and let everything else go uncaught.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are throwing PHP's generic Exception

```
throw new \Exception("My exception");
```

but you catch the Exception from the current namespace

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
```

Assuming your controller is in `Application\Controller`, you either have to declare

```
use \Exception;
```

above your class to [import the global Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) into the current namespace or

```
} catch (\Exception $e) {
```

to catch PHP's global Exception.

Comment: Side questions: will doing `catch (\Exception $e) {` catch every exception that may occur, or just those that extend the `Exception` class (e.g. would it catch `class ORMException extends Exception`?) If not, is there a way of catching any exception (and is it worth trying to do so, since I assume libraries that are probably coded should extend `Exception` for their custom exception handling, or am I mistaken?)

Comment: See GordonMs comment for that

Comment: @user since all Exceptions extend PHP's global Exception, catch \Exception will catch any exception.