# PDOException could not find driver on Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to install Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine from this [manual](http://marco-pivetta.com/doctrine-orm-zf2-tutorial) and have some problem with PDO driver. Doctrine is trying to connect to my MySQL server and then trying to create schema:

> ./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create

I have this error:

```
 [PDOException]
 could not find driver
```

This is my config/autoload/doctrine.local.php:

```
 return array(   'doctrine' => array(
     'connection' => array(
       'orm_default' => array(
         'driverClass' =>'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
         'params' => array(
           'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql', 
           'host'     => 'localhost',
           'port'     => '3306',
           'user'     => 'root',
           'password' => 'password',
           'dbname'   => 'blog', 
 )))));
```

I have PHP 5.3.5 and i have uncommented `;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` in php.ini, also it wasn't commented. But `php -m | grep -i pdo` gives me:

> PDO

only. I'm know that it should be `pdo_mysql` too, but i'm trying everything and it isn't appear.

Anyway, PDO driver is works well at my another project on this server, where I'm not using Zend and Doctrine.

Comment: When doing `php -m` you should see both `PDO` and `pdo_mysql`. Since the last one is the adapter. If `pdo_mysql` isn't listed then the extension is not correctly activated. It's that easy :)

Comment: @netiul How I should activate extension correctly? There is no manual to install driver, it should be install by default on my server as i understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ohh yes. I'm just solved a problem. I'm going to this [page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) and thought to find my php.ini files anywhere else perhaps PHP folder - it was one more in `"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5"` and there row

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

weren't uncomment. I'm uncommented it and it works!

Comment: well, I too had same problem but since i am using sqlite i uncommented ;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll and i came to know about this error when i added a try catch while connecting sqlite DB in ZF2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108482/how-to-catch-exceptions-in-your-zf2-controllers (i know this is not related to what the question is asked but I am sure this will help someone to quickly find the issue)