# Catching ServiceManager Exceptions

Tags: php, exception, zend-framework2

When I use the service manager to get an object which throws an exception during its initialization, I'm unable to catch this one with a simple :

```
try {
    $hybridAuth = $this->getServiceManager()->get('HybridAuth');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump('catched');
}
```

Instead the Exception is catched by Zend with a famous "An error occurred" page

[image]

Which shows me a "snowball" of thrown Exceptions (because a service could not be initialized and others are depending on, etc)

How can I catch the exception (and then put some code logic) to prevent Zend from catching it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you problem isn't on how to catch `ServiceManager` Exceptions.

The way you're doing it is wrong :

```
catch (Exception $e)
```

Will catch exception from the current namespace. What You need is to catch PHP global exception. 
You have the same issue as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108482/how-to-catch-exceptions-in-your-zf2-controllers).

Change your code by this one :

```
try {
     $hybridAuth = $this->getServiceManager()->get('HybridAuth');
    }
catch (\Exception $e) {
    var_dump('catched');
   }
```

Or import the global php exception by adding this :

```
use \Exception;
```